# Which NSCoder does .pbxproj format use?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nscoding, nscoder

Inside the .xcodeproj bundle, main project data is actually stored in the .pbxproj file. It is quite obviously an archived dictionary, but I have not been able to find which coder did Apple use? Is it a custom subclass of `NSCoder`, or is it documented and I didn't look hard enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually an old-style property list, so I'd say the NSDictionary facilities for writing a dictionary to a file. But there are also embedded comments, so it might be some sort of custom code.

Comment: It is custom and undocumented.

Comment: Once you mentioned the name of the format, I dig out the docs and specs pretty quickly. Their archiving indeed seems custom (the comments mentioned). Docs mention that archiving existed in OpenStep, but this is probably not used here (comments). However the unarchiver, according to documentation under title "Old-Style ASCII Property Lists", can be decoded using propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription: in class NSPropertyListSerialization (with argument NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat).